# weird Chrome webstore install stats

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have a Chrome extension in the Chrome Webstore. I noticed a difference between the stats showing in old and new developer dashboard.

In the old developer dashboard, the stats view shows 3 installs on 28th of January, and 1 install on the 30th. 
[image: old]

While in the new dashboard, it shows 5 installs on the 28th, and 3 installs on the 30th.
[image: new]

How are they calculated, why are they different and which one is accurate?

Comment: As interested as I am in the answer, I'm afraid that this is not a programming question. However, you have a clue in the bottom picture where it mentions "the number of install requests per day. This includes successful, unsuccessful, and unknown statuses". The difference might be there.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko That is a big clue, thanks. Now I have to figure out what it means that an install status is unsuccessful or unknown. I posted it here because I saw some other questions very distantly related to programming having a lot of upvotes, but I guess it's not the perfect place for it.